# SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch issue

Tags: smtp, mail-server, reverse-dns

According to MXToolbox my server has a problem.

Please review:
https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=smtp%3awebmaus.net&run=toolpage

The tool shows a 'SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch' and I don't have an idea why.
My PTR Records look like:

```
158.22.202.116.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR     158.22.202.116.pleiades.webmaus.net.
```

I've also got A/AAAA records added for pleiades. Any hints on where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reverse DNS: closed PTR-A loop

SMTP servers check "closed loop" of PTR and A records.
IP address -> [ PTR record ] -> Name -> [ A record ] -> IP address
Rogue nets can set PTR to any name they like.

There seems to be no A record for 158.22.202.116.pleiades.webmaus.net.

Comment: I put in an A and AAAA record and that worked, thanks alot for the hint.